# How to correctly remove 'unique' column attribute in users table column in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

Following tutorials early on left me with a 'username' column that is set to unique. I would like to change that, so that my unique user identifier is tied to the email.

I've done the steps I found:

- composer require doctrine/dbal
- php artisan make:migration modify_users_table --table=users

My migration contains:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('username')->unique(false)->change();
    });
}
```

However, when I run the command 'php artisan migrate' I get

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1280 Incorrect index name '' (SQL: alter table users add unique (us
  ername))

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1280 Incorrect index name ''

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1280 Incorrect index name ''

---

From my initial research it appears that the issue is with my index:

```
users_username_unique
```

**So my question is:**

Is it safe to remove that index, then run the migration?
If that is the correct way to do it, does my migration need to have something like this:

```
$table->dropUnique('users_username_unique');
```

Then will this command automatically create a correct, non-unique, index?

```
$table->string('username')->unique(false)->change();
```

Comment: Why not to fix it via MySQL? If you gonna use this migration again, you cant remove `unique()` after that.

Comment: I had thought about that, because you're right, I won't be able to use the migrations again without some editing. But I'm pretty sure I can remove the ->unique() from the initial user table migration, then remove these alterations - then I might be able to use the migrations again in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop a unique index and add a plain index.

```
$table->dropUnique(['username']);
$table->index('username');
```

If need, add a unique index for email.

```
$table->unique('email');
```

[Database: Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations)

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is what I'm looking for. I will attempt this, then mark as answer

Answer (score 2):

For dropUnique() method, You have to create a new migration,

```
 Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->dropUnique('username');  
 });
```

or If need, you can add a unique index for username.

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unique('username');  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new migration and use [`dropUnique()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#dropping-indexes) method:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropUnique('users_username_unique');
});
```

Then run `composer du` and `php artisan migrate` commands to execute the migration.